# JQuery - Click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can anyone spot why the `ShowVideo` click event won't fire to make the JQueryUI dialog show? I'm sure it's something relatively simple that i'm overlooking.

Here is my page's relevant code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false }); //Hide the modal on page load.
        });

        $("#ShowVideo").click(function () {

            $("#dialog").dialog("option", "show", "slow"); // Should show the MF'ing dialog but never gets hit!
        });
    });

  </script>


</head>
<body>

        <h2Links</h2>
        <ul class="SidebarMenu">
            <li id="ShowVideo">Test Popup</li>
        </ul>


   <div id="dialog" title="Test">

  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Quick JS fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnp9v/

Comment: Off topic: You have nested ready() functions for some reason.

Comment: You're just changing an option, not really showing the dialog ?

Comment: Thanks Isherwood - copy and paste issue I didn't spot. Not sure why the question got downvoted though - what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are changing an option, not "open"-ing the dialog:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnp9v/4/

Comment: This would be better if you'd retained the 'slow' option.

Comment: @isherwood I did.  Look at the dialog setup.

Comment: It doesn't transition in Chrome.

Comment: Not in mine either.  Don't know about other browsers, or if it is jsfiddle.

Comment: The transition wasn't overly important, i'll work on that, thank you Tim.

Answer (score 1):

The method is `open`.

```
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
```